# FCM уведомления не доходят

Tags: php, java, android, fcm

Не приходят push уведомления. При отсылке сервер гугла возвращает `{"multicast_id":410383576077558298,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1576316927466102%b078b91ff9fd7ecd"}]}` но сообщение так и не приходит. registrationId генерируется при старте приложения и отсылается на наш сервер и потом подставляется в массив registrationIds. Пробовал сделать рассылку с консоли fcm - сообщения приходят( там без registrationId конкретного устройства, приходит сразу на все зарегистрированные на гугловском сервере запущенные версии). В чем может быть проблема?

```
<?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', '********' );

$registrationIds = array( '*************' );

// prep the bundle
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
    'title'     => 'This is a title.',
    'body'  => 'This is a body text',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);

$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
?>
```

Класс принимающий сообщения на стороне андроид

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCMService";
    final String ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID = "GPSTrackerPush";

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String mToken) {
        super.onNewToken(mToken);
        sendTokenToServer(mToken);
        Log.e("TOKEN - ",mToken);
    }

    private void sendTokenToServer(String mToken){
        getRequest request = new getRequest();
        if(MainActivity.authData.isAuth){
            request.execute(MainActivity.authData.getBaseUrl() + "auth.php?token_fcm=" + mToken);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        remoteMessage.getData();

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            try {
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
                String jsonMessage = data.getString("extra_information");
                Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: \n" +
                        "Extra Information: " + jsonMessage);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(); //get title
            String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(); //get message
            String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction(); //get click_action

            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Title: " + title);
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + message);
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification click_action: " + click_action);

            sendNotification(title, message,click_action);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages() {

    }

    private void sendNotification(String title,String messageBody, String click_action) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Notification.Builder notificationBuilder = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            createNotificationChannel();
            notificationBuilder = (Notification.Builder) new Notification.Builder(this, ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        }else{
            notificationBuilder = (Notification.Builder) new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(messageBody)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
                    .setLights(Color.MAGENTA, 500, 1000)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        }

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(888 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    ANDROID_CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Foreground Service Channel",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            );
            serviceChannel.enableVibration(true);
            serviceChannel.enableLights(true);
            serviceChannel.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION),
                    new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE)
                    .build());
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В fields замените ключ data на notification, или, скорее, добавьте его туда.